# Enumerate machine with Windows OS in LAN

Tags: c++, c, netapi32

I want to enumerate all Windows based machines in the network in workgroup. For that I'm using NetApi32.dll functions. In my network, I've windows, mac and linux OS installed. How can we filter out Windows Machines only. Given below is the code I am using. Please comment if I'm doing any mistake or is there any alternate method to achieve it.

```
BOOLEAN
LocalEnumServers(const WCHAR *pcwszDomainName) {
    DWORD dwCount;
    DWORD dwLevel = 101;
    NET_API_STATUS Status;
    HRESULT hResult = S_OK;
    DWORD dwEntriesRead = 0;
    BOOLEAN bResult = FALSE;
    DWORD dwTotalEntries = 0;
    DWORD dwResumeHandle = 0;
    LPSERVER_INFO_101 pTmpBuf;
    LPSERVER_INFO_101 pBuf = NULL;
    TCHAR szOSName[_MAX_PATH] = _T("");
    DWORD dwServerType = SV_TYPE_SERVER;
    DWORD dwPrefMaxLen = MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH;

    if (NULL == pcwszDomainName)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    pBuf = NULL;

    Status = NetServerEnum(
                        NULL,
                        dwLevel,
                        (LPBYTE *)&pBuf,
                        dwPrefMaxLen,
                        &dwEntriesRead,
                        &dwTotalEntries,
                        dwServerType,
                        /*(LPCSTR)*/pcwszDomainName,
                        &dwResumeHandle
                        );
    if ((NERR_Success == Status || Status == ERROR_MORE_DATA) && pBuf != NULL) {
        pTmpBuf = (SERVER_INFO_101 *)pBuf;
        for (dwCount = 0; dwCount < dwEntriesRead; dwCount++) {
            wprintf(L"Server name = %15s, Server type = 0x%08X, Verson = (%u:%u), Comment = %s\n", pTmpBuf[dwCount].sv101_name, pTmpBuf[dwCount].sv101_type, pTmpBuf[dwCount].sv101_version_major & MAJOR_VERSION_MASK, pTmpBuf[dwCount].sv101_version_minor, pTmpBuf[dwCount].sv101_comment);
            //wprintf(L"Server name -> %s, Server type -> 0x%X, Platform ID -> 0x%X, Verson -> (%u:%u)\n", pTmpBuf[dwCount].sv101_name, pTmpBuf[dwCount].sv101_type, pTmpBuf[dwCount].sv101_platform_id, pTmpBuf[dwCount].sv101_version_major & MAJOR_VERSION_MASK, pTmpBuf[dwCount].sv101_version_minor);

            if (
                SV_TYPE_WINDOWS != (SV_TYPE_WINDOWS & pTmpBuf[dwCount].sv101_type)      &&
                SV_TYPE_SERVER_NT != (SV_TYPE_SERVER_NT & pTmpBuf[dwCount].sv101_type)  &&
                SV_TYPE_NT != (SV_TYPE_NT & pTmpBuf[dwCount].sv101_type)
                ) {
                wprintf(L"Flag check (%u, %u, %u)\n", SV_TYPE_WINDOWS != (SV_TYPE_WINDOWS & pTmpBuf[dwCount].sv101_type),
                    SV_TYPE_SERVER_NT != (SV_TYPE_SERVER_NT & pTmpBuf[dwCount].sv101_type),
                    SV_TYPE_NT != (SV_TYPE_NT & pTmpBuf[dwCount].sv101_type));

                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        wprintf(L"NetServerEnum failed (Err -> %u)\n", GetLastError());
    }

    if (pBuf != NULL) {
        NetApiBufferFree(pBuf);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    LocalEnumServers(L"workgroup");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you use SV_TYPE_WINDOWS instead of SV_TYPE_SERVER in the servertype section.

Comment: Doesn't work. Even if the name is SV_TYPE_WINDOWS, the flag evaluates to FALSE for each machine.

Answer (score 0):

For UNIX type system you can add if condition and perform AND with predefined macro for unix system and sv type u r getting. But for MAC there is an issue.